# Open a new window for emacs from terminal in mac

Tags: mac

How do I get the emacs "graphical window" to pop up in a separate window when i type in 'emacs' in the terminal on Mac OSX? On linux when you type in emacs in an xterm window, it pops up a new window, but in OSX it opens in the terminal window.

For example, when I type in 'emacs SomeFile' it opens up/creates SomeFile within terminal when I'd like it to pop up a separate window like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I *think* the problem is that emacs for OS X doesn't have X window support in the version that is shipped.

So, alternatively, there's [emacs for OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/). Or maybe you want [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/), which is a bit more integrated into OS X.

> Based on GNU Emacs, Aquamacs integrates perfectly with OS X thanks to its specially adapted user interface.

[image]